# Color distortion after coming out from suspend on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, suspend, amd-graphics

The display colors are totally distorted after resuming from suspension. This **does not happen** if I manually suspend but if the PC suspends itself after the specified time on settings, when I resume the colors are totally broken. If I restart gnome-shell (Alt + F2 - r) everything goes back to normal. What is the difference between manually suspend and automatic suspension?

I installed oibaf/graphics-drivers but I only get a black screen with a random underscore on boot. radeon.modeset=0 is not a viable option. What can I do?

System info:

- Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
- Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
- Ubuntu 18.04 (default installation)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to "Color distortion after coming out from suspend on Ubuntu 18.04"

This is an answer; not a question. My previous answer was deleted by a moderator for being a new question. But in any case, have since found this solution: Install graphics drivers again to overwrite what ever started the issue. In Ubuntu that would be done by following the instructions from here: https://linoxide.com/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu/