# How to automatically restart Gnome Shell every time the PC comes out from suspend

Tags: gnome, suspend, gnome-shell

Since I did not receive any answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051373/color-distortion-after-coming-out-from-suspend-on-ubuntu-18-04) and I have to manually restart gnome-shell each time the PC comes back from suspend to correct the distorted colors, I would like to know how to automatically restart Gnome Shell after suspend instead of doing Alt + F2 - r.

Installed Gnome extensions: Dash to Panel and Arc Menu.
This is not a duplicate of a previous question. This specifically about automatically restarting Gnome Shell after coming out from suspend. Questions are totally different.

**Edit:** following the suggestions on comments:

a. Created a file on /etc/systemd/system called restart-gnome-shell.service and add the following:

```
[Unit] 
Description=Restart Gnome-Shell
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service] 
Type=oneshot 
RemainAfterExit=yes 
ExecStop=-/path/to/script.sh

[Install] 
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

The script.sh contents are:

```
#! /bin/bash
gnome-shell --replace
```

The script has execution permissions and I enabled and started the service which was recognized by systemctl. This did not work.

This is the status after waking up from suspend:

```
● restart-gnome-shell.service - Restart Gnome-Shell
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/restart-gnome-shell.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

jul 08 12:51:07 Enrique-PC systemd[1]: Started Restart Gnome-Shell.
jul 08 15:53:08 Enrique-PC systemd[1]: restart-gnome-shell.service: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
jul 08 15:53:08 Enrique-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Restart Gnome-Shell...
jul 08 15:53:08 Enrique-PC restart-gnome-shell.sh[2119]: Window manager warning: Unsupported session type
jul 08 15:53:08 Enrique-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Restart Gnome-Shell.
```

b. Created an executable script on /lib/systemd/system-sleep with the following contents:

```
case "${1}" in
    post)
         gnome-shell --replace
;;
esac
```

It did not work.

Comment: You can try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend with the command `gnome-shell --replace`.

Comment: @pomsky thanks, but that command never completes because it says for example that Dropbox client is already registered and never continues. Similar issues with other Ubuntu AppIndicators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color distortion after coming out from suspend on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051373/color-distortion-after-coming-out-from-suspend-on-ubuntu-18-04). Please edit that question with the additional information.

Comment: You may have a GNOME extension conflict. Please edit your question to list your set of enabled GNOME extensions shown at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema thanks, I edited the question with the installed extensions.

Comment: @user535733 This is not a duplicate of a previous question. This is specifically about automatically restarting Gnome Shell after coming out from suspend. Questions are different.

Comment: Temporarily turn off these two extensions, and retest the suspend problem. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema thanks. The problem is not with suspension. That was the other question that I mentioned at the beginning of this one. My problem is with the suggested command to restart Gnome Shell and even after disabling those extensions, the command `gnome-shell - - replace` never finishes to work on terminal and if I stop it everything freezes.

Comment: I think the command that you want ends in `-r`, or `--replace` (no spaces). What video driver are you using?

Comment: @heynnema sorry yes, I was answering in the phone and did not noticed that it added spaces, but I'm using the one without the spaces. The graphics card is Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM] Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]. I'm using the default driver that came with Ubuntu 18.04. I have no option to change it under Additional drivers.

Comment: @pomsky thanks, I'm not sure if it completes the Gnome Shell restart because if I execute it directly on terminal it never completes and you said it is supposed to complete.

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong. I meant that command is *not* supposed to *complete*.

Comment: This looks like your problem, although it is already old: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/how-can-i-automatically-restart-gnome-shell-coming-out-of-suspend-mode

Comment: @pomsky thank you, in that case yes, it seems to be working. I will try your solution with that command then.

Comment: @vanadium yes I already looked at that question but apparently It does not work on newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps try this: https://mariogalan.com/en/content/execute-script-after-suspend-ubuntu-1604, which suggests adding a script to /lib/systemd/system-sleep to perform an action on wake.

Comment: @pomsky I added to the question the process that I follow according to the link that you shared. Can you please check if I did anything wrong.

Comment: @vanadium thanks, I also tried with the solution that you shared but it did not work. I also added what I did to the question. Can you please check?

Comment: @pomsky thanks. Yes, in the question I use /path/to/script.sh as an example but I used the correct path.  And yes, I enabled the service.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I am trying the same things.

Comment: @RyanWard noup... But it only happens if the PC suspends itself after the specified time not if you manually suspend it. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Change your script from this:

```bash
case "${1}" in
    post)
         gnome-shell --replace
;;
esac
```

To this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0`
    # if no pre suspend action required
    sleep 1
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` 
    # if no post suspend action required
    sleep 2
    gnome-shell --replace
    ;;
esac
```

For sure you are missing `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script. Most of the rest of the proposed changes are not be necessary but informative.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why it is not working. I used the script that you suggest, copy it to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply is a bit late, but I will post my method, maybe it will be useful to someone :-). !!! Only works with Xorg!!!.

The solution I found (a trick) is to create a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` that stores a value ("1") in a `file` every time it wakes up from sleep, and I have another script that is always running that checks the contents of that `file` and when it is equal to "1" it runs the shell restart code and then changes the contents of the `file` to "0". The code to restart the shell is also a "trick" as I haven't found a command to do this, where I have to use xdotool to simulate keypress and mouse click.

Scripts:

- /lib/systemd/system-sleep/resume_status

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
  sleep 5 
  echo "1" > PATH-TO-FILE/FILE
fi
```

`sleep 5` is used to wait the system to enter graphical environment

- a user script to check the resume from sleep (placed somewhere in your HOME) :

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    check=$(sed '1q;d'  PATH-TO-FILE/FILE)
    if [[ "$check" == "1" ]]; then
        xdotool key alt+F2
        sleep 1
        xdotool click 1
        xdotool type 'r'
        xdotool key Return
        echo "0" > PATH-TO-FILE/FILE
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Change PATH-TO-FILE/FILE to match your case and make sure xdotool is installed.

I have been using this method for a while now and it is working fine.